# Bottleneck in stress testing Node web server

Tags: node.js, multithreading, express, node-modules, libuv

This question is really bugging me for past few days and I have no logical explanation of this whatsoever. It came up after me testing out how epoll and libuv generally works in Node and by experimenting scalability of an express / http server. My tests were diversified into 2 segments.

1. Creating http server with single Node process.
2. Creating http server with multiple Node processes trough clustering.

I also had a 2nd stress testing server that used JMeter to stress test on how much concurrent connections can it handle per second.

single Node process code:

```
const express = require('express')
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const app = express()
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));


setInterval(function () {

    console.log("Per sec: "+ currentSec);
    currentSec = 0

    console.log("------------------------")

}, 1000);


app.get('/', (req, res) => {
 currentSec++
 res.send("OK")
})
app.listen(3000, "XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX");
```

multiple Node processes

```
const express = require('express')
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')

var cluster = require('cluster');
var numCPUs = require('os').cpus().length;


if (cluster.isMaster) {


    setInterval(function () { //syncronizer , ram - file
    // i had some logic here for counting global per second
    }, 1000);


    for (var i = 0; i < numCPUs; i++) {
        const worker = cluster.fork();
    }

} else {
    var app = express();

    app.get('/', async function (req, res) {
        res.send("ok")
        return
    });

    app.listen(3000, 'XXX.34.XXX.121');
}
```

Both codes were counting how much requests were incoming per second, but I've also had option to see it inside JMeter so it wasn't really a problem.
Before anything, I want to clarify that I made a very simple GET route on purpose as I wanted to test the load on simple web server that does not use help of any libuv threads which could stress out cores on machine even more, but rather using only main event loop thread to process socket writing which was the actually purpose of testing (understanding if bottleneck is in Kernel or rather in main event loop processing the application data) and managing to balance out 1 core per process as much as possible.

I've read quiet interesting documentations on how Node processes network I/O communication and the way it uses epoll to gather file descriptors which it uses after appending aplpication data to write towards socket with help of system calls. I've understood the complexity part of it and the fact that all socket writing and reading is being done by Kernel itself and not Node, leaving only Node to handle with application data layer and **it doing non blocking system call later on when finished with simple processing** after which Kernel uses to trigger driver calls towards network adapter. Upon receiving the data from client, Kernel gets triggered by hardware interrupts and then notifies epoll about changes in file descriptors, making the whole writing / read process pretty straightforward, abstractly at least.

Results that I've got were kind of shocking taking the fact that my guess on start was that Node would have the same result in both scenarios(either using multi processes or single process). My assumption was that the complexity of reading file descriptors, appending data to socket and getting information from Kernel upon some event such new socket opened would result same if there were multi cores involved into processing compared to just 1, making clustering pretty redundant in terms of processing **simple http** requests like that. My theory was that the overhead in ICP communication via pipe would be slowing it even more, making one thread, 1 process Node faster or same compared to multi core architecture via clustering. In my head, this was something like diversifying `for loop` that does 100k cycles of some math calculations towards 8 cores vs just using 1 core to do that in first place, assuming this 100k cycles operation was being triggered by some http event and then diversified around other cores from master process. In practice, this would work if there was no overhead in communication from a single process(in our case master server) that diversifies work towards 8 other cores, making it much faster to process with 1 core based on some event trigger like GET request in our case due to overheads in communication if we used multi cores for this. Operations that main event loop is doing when handling TCP socket and doing a system call seemed so trivial to me CPU complexity wise, that I thought achieving parallelism in terms of multicore usage was pretty redundant due to the fact that bottleneck in the end was Kernel which was doing all the final touch and sending socket out to the network driver and that Node's process was just doing small non blocking portion.

I imagined the process as follows (in this example lets look at this 1st scenario using just 1 Node process).

**Scenario number 1 (single process):**

JMeter triggers some number of requests, lets say N. Network adapter at server side receives it and does hardware interrupt towards Kernel where Kernel then notifies epoll that there are some new events which it has to handle, and then main event loop after some amount of time (lets say K) starts going trough all the events that came over and starts writting application data towards the socket.

[image: Wait for epoll explained]

Upon gathering file descriptors and writting of application data (in this case "ok" content), it does system call to Kernel that socket is ready and that it's ready for send and then Kernel sends it over to network driver and then the packet is being sent over towards the client that did request in first place.

**What happens in scenario nr. 2 when it comes to multi processing and clustering?**

Even though every worker process is 'listening' on same port, in reality it's not like this. Master process and master's main event loop is the one that is listening on this port and all it does it registers workers in separate tcp communication channel, or pipe, depending on implementation to later on offload the socket application data appending, making the bottleneck just this main master process which uses 1 event loop same as in first scenario (*WHICH CREATED BIGGEST CONFUSION HERE!*).
Upon client sending over HTTP request, what happens ***I think*** for every request is pretty similar to first scenario. Kernel receives hardware interrupt, then it notifies epoll from first master process that new event occurred and then main event loop takes file descriptor it has to read from and what happens then is that main master process which forked all other clusters is offloading that file descriptor / work towards other processes in terms notifying it about some work they have to do (in this case, it *possibly* gives them file descriptor they have to manipulate with). By this, we achieve parallelism by using multi cores and actually trying to increase speed of processing something **very simple** in terms of CPU consumption which is **non blocking system call and application data append**

**RESULTS**

Before mentioning anything, I was testing this on 8core CPU server with 16GB ram and 1/1Gbps bandwith.
JMeter was using another exactly same spec machine.
Every request had no `keep-alive` header, meaning that sockets were reopening every time.
RTT was aprox 8 ms between client and server.

*1st scenario using server running on 1 Node process(with 1 main event loop).*

Server was receiving and processing approximately 2,500 - 3,500 concurrent connections per second.

*2nd scenario using server running on 8 Node processes(with 8 main event loops).*

Server was receiving and processing approximately 11,00 - 13,000 concurrent connections per second.

***CONFUSIN SUMMARIZED***

Based on all the things I researched about and taking the fact that all  these processes do is simple non blocking system requests, my question is, how is it possible that 8 processes managed to achieve better result taking in consideration that bottlenecks were the same in both tests? Bottleneck on global level is Kernel - OS and in our application (both scenarios) its a Node server listening on some particular port using 1 main event loop and epoll to poll the ready sockets. In first scenario we had 1 process listening on port 3000 (1 main event loop) and in second scenario we had also 1 process(main master) with its main event loop listening on port 3000 and offloading every request to workers to fill that file descriptor - >> socket with application data and then finish off with system call. It just doesn't make sense to me that 8 processes performed better then this 1 process in first scenario taking the fact that operations they had to do when receiving event from epoll are very trivial which in the end are just non blocking system calls.

**My unconfirmed explanation why it happened?**

Lets assume that network adapter due to high bandwidth and low message size can accept much more then 10,000 connections per second(in our case). Now it gets me to a point where only explanation for this is that all articles I've read about clustering and the way of how complex operations for I/O networking that main event loop is doing are very untrue. Assuming 1 node process achieved 3,000 concurrent requests and 8 processes did 12,000 explains that it indeed managed to process more connections by providing more core power to process `something` under the hood after epoll received file descriptor. Every article I've read so far explained that this process is not CPU heavy at all as it only does **simple non blocking system call after it receives descriptors and fills application data**. My only explanation is that before the system call, filling application data is **INDEED CPU heavy in some way** and I need someone to actually point me in the right direction. Also, there might be a possibility that articles were wrong when they were referring that master process is sending out file descriptors / socket locations to other worker processes, but rather I think there might be a chance that on start when Node is started it just registers all 8 different epolls to Kernel so when new request comes in, it does some round robin principle and it is informing 8 different epoll listeners about new request and not going trough master process directly(just my guess). By this, we achieve multi core parallelism for handling expensive operation, which is possibly data application appending towards socket. If this is true and that there are actually 8 different epoll listeners, then this means that processing I/O network socket and writing application data is indeed heavy and that bottleneck is rather in Node application and how it processes sockets and appends application data before doing system calls.

Does someone have any logical explanation for this?

Comment: such a beautiful novel bro :)

Comment: Not helping me that much : )